# How to get a Observable of UIImageView is Empty by Using Rxswift?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I want to get a Observable of UIImageView is Empty by Using Rxswift.

Here is my code:

```
let usernameValid = firstTextField.rx.text.orEmpty
    .map { $0.characters.count >= 1 }
    .shareReplay(1)

let passwordValid = secondTextField.rx.text.orEmpty
    .map { $0.characters.count >= 1 }
    .shareReplay(1)

let everythingValid = Observable.combineLatest(usernameValid, passwordValid) { $0 && $1 }
    .shareReplay(1)

everythingValid.bindTo(submitButton.rx.isEnabled).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

I want get similar Observable like usernameValid.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `.rx.image` property on `UIImageView` is of type `UIBindingObserver`. This type does not implement `ObservableType`, hence you will not be able to simply write `imageView.rx.image.orDefault(defaultImage)`.

If you'd like to observe the `image` property of a `UIImageView`, you'll need to use KVO.

```
// this is "equivalent" to `firstTextField.rx.text`
let imageObs: Observable<UIImage?> = imageView.rx.observe(Optional<UIImage>.self, "image")

// default image will act in the same way the empty string is used in the case of `orEmpty`
let defaultImage = UIImage(named: "defaultImage")!
let imageWithDefaultObs: Observable<UIImage> = imageObs.map { 
  // return defaultImage when $0 is nil
  return $0 ?? defaultImage
}
```

You can also write the `isEmpty` property as an extension to `Reactive`

```swift
extension Reactive where Base: UIImageView {
    var isEmpty: Observable<Bool> {
        return observe(UIImage.self, "image").map{ $0 == nil }
    } 
}
// Usage:
imageView.rx.isEmpty.subscribe(onNext: { isEmpty in 
    /** do something */ 
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 1):

swift 5

```
lazy var image: Observable<UIImage?> = imageView.rx.observe(UIImage.self, "image")
```